# Multiple table join in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, teradata, sqoop

I have migrated Teradata tables' data into hive .

Now I have to build summary tables on top of imported data. Summary table needs to be built from five source tables

If I go with joins I'll need to join five tables is it possible in hive ? or should I break the query in five parts? 
what should be advisable approach for this problem?

Please suggest

Answer (score 14):

Five way joins in hive are of course possible and also (naturally) likely slow to very slow.

You should consider co-partitioning the tables on

- identical partition columns
- identical number of partitions

Other options include **hints**. For example consider if one of the tables were large and the others small. You may then be able to use ***streamtble*** hint

*Assuming a is large:*

```
SELECT /*+ STREAMTABLE(a) */ a.val, b.val, c.val, d.val, e.val 
FROM a JOIN b ON (a.key = b.key1) JOIN c ON (c.key = b.key1) join d on (d.key = c.key) join e on (e.key = d.key)
```

Adapted from :  https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Joins
:

> All five tables are joined in a single map/reduce job and the values
>   for a particular value of the key for tables b, c,d, and e are
>   buffered in the memory in the reducers. Then for each row retrieved
>   from a, the join is computed with the buffered rows. If the
>   STREAMTABLE hint is omitted, Hive streams the rightmost table in the
>   join.

Another hint is the ***mapjoin*** that is useful to cache small tables in memory.

*Assuming a is large and b,c,d,e are small enough to fit in memory of each mapper:*

```
 SELECT /*+ MAPJOIN(b,c,d,e) */  a.val, b.val, c.val, d.val, e.val 
 FROM a JOIN b ON (a.key = b.key1) JOIN c ON (c.key = b.key1) 
 join d on (d.key = c.key) join e on (e.key = d.key)
```

Comment: hey thanks!! I'm looking into how can i improve the performace of hive join query

Comment: @chhayavishwakarma . Yes - and this answer provides those methods.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can [join multiple tables](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Joins#LanguageManualJoins-Examples) in a single query. This allows many opportunities for Hive to make optimizations that couldn't be done if you broke it into separate queries.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy Beard !! I'm looking into how can i improve the performance of hive join query ,what will be best practice for doing such joins in optimized way